# No syntax highlighting for python traceback - pygments

Tags: python, markdown, pygments

I'm using pygments version 1.6 on a blog to do some syntax highlighting (via the CodeHilite extension for markdown)

The syntax highlighting for python is great. However, if I try to use the `pytb` lexer for highlighting a python traceback it's very underwhelming

I can check that it is available:

```
for lexer in pygments.lexers.get_all_lexers():
    print lexer

........
('Python Traceback', ('pytb',), ('*.pytb',), ('text/x-python-traceback',))
.......
```

but it looks nothing like the demo:
http://pygments.org/demo/61075/?style=native

instead, it highlights to a basic white font.

[said blog post here](http://www.thebrokendesk.com/post/installing-lightblue-on-osx-109/)

**EDIT**

*My code:*

```
<div class="codehilite">
    <pre>
        <span class="go">TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases</span>
        <span class="go"> class _AsyncDeviceInquiry does not correctly implement protocol IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelegate: the signature for method deviceInquiryComplete:error:aborted: is v@:@iB instead of v@:@iZ</span>
    </pre>
</div>
```

*Code from the Demo*

```
<div class="syntax">
    <pre>
        :
        <span class="nc">ImportError</span>
        :
        <span class="n-Identifier">('No module named TMPD54~1.049d4d1330606d5fa968586a2810c4fc', '[DimShuffle{x}(TensorConstant{2.0})]')</span>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: http://pygments.org/demo/61075/?style=native is 404.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that Pygments is working just fine. I suggest viewing the source of your markdown output and the source of the demo you linked to. I suspect that both will have spans littered throughout the trackback marking up the various parts.

Of course, without you providing the actual output you are getting, I can only guess. But if I'm correct, you need to provide the CSS to style that markup. Python-Markdown does not provide the CSS for you. It is your responsibility to provide that. If I recall correctly, Pygments offers a command to generate a CSS file. I suggest you check their documentation.

As a case in point, the demo you point to allows you to change to different themes. The actual html output by pygments never changes, only a different CSS file is used to style the same markup.

Comment: The CSS is from a file downloaded via the link I posted.
Pygments (or Codehilite) does not add any style tags to the snippet when `pytb` is used. However, it does when `python` is used.

Comment: also, the html output does change depending on the lexer used. Different lexers recognize different keywords. (i.e. using python will  tag `import` differently than the html lexer).